# JUnit test cases for Spring Service Layer

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, groovy, junit4

I am trying to configure JUnit and write test cases for Service layer of Spring 3.2 MVC application. I couldnt find much information on how to configure the JUnit from scratch and make it work for Spring service layer. here is my problem

I dont really know what version of junit to be used so i just grabbed the latest version

Maven junit dependancy

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My service Class

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements IAuthService, ApplicationContextAware,
        org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener<org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent> {

public Collection<? extends String> addCommandPermissions(Session session, CommandMetadata command) {

    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
    String commandName = command.getBeanName();
    String defaultAdministerPermission = command.getAdministerPermission()
    String defaultExecutePermission = command.getExecutePermission()
    String overrideAdminPermission = null;
    String overrideExecPermission = null;
    String finalAdministerPermission = overrideAdminPermission == null ? defaultAdministerPermission
            : overrideAdminPermission;
    command.setAdministerPermission(finalAdministerPermission);
    result.add(finalAdministerPermission);
    String finalFxecutePermission = overrideExecPermission == null ? defaultExecutePermission
            : overrideExecPermission;
    command.setExecutePermission(finalFxecutePermission);
    result.add(finalFxecutePermission);
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(command);
        session.flush();
    } finally {
        // TODO - more swallowed exceptions.
    }
    return result;
}

// some other methods
}
```

My Test Class(used groovy partially)

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import com.dc.core.security.service.impl.AuthService
import com.dc.core.behavior.command.model.impl.CommandMetadata;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory
import org.hibernate.classic.Session

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
public class AuthServiceTest extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    private MockHttpSession mockHttpSession;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appContext

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory

    private Session mockHibernateSession = Mockito.mock(org.hibernate.classic.Session.class);

    private CommandMetadata commandMetadata = new CommandMetadata();

    public void setUp() {
       appContext.getBeanFactory().registerScope("request", new RequestScope())
       MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest()

        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request)
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes)
        CurrentRequestProperties currentRequestProperties = appContext.getBean("currentRequestProperties")
        session = sessionHandler.initiateSession(sessionFactory, currentRequestProperties)


    }

    public void testAddCommandPermissions() {
        commandMetadata.beanName = "TestBean"
        commandMetadata.administerPermission = "TestBean.administer"
        commandMetadata.executePermission = "TestBean.execute"
        Collection<String> results = authorizationService.addCommandPermissions(session, commandMetadata);
        assertTrue(results.contains("TestBean.administer"))
    }

    public void testCanary() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I run my test case am getting the below error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getBeanFactory() on null object

I think cause of the issue is appContext is not injected properly hence am getting NPE. But I couldnt solve this issue. I really appreciate someone's help on this

Comment: It's just a guess but don't You need something like `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` on the tested class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the Spring JUnit class runner. You should also use the @Test annotations instead of extending TestCase.

e.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I Create My ServiceTest Hope this will help you

Just want to add some idea and im not sure if it is a best practice or not so correct me if theres something wrong.

- **MYPROJECT**

  -**src**

  --hibernate.cfg.xml

  -**test**

  --TestPackage

  ---BaseServiceTest.class

  ---BlogspotServiceTest.class

  -**web**

  --WEB-INF

  ---blogspot-servlet-test.xml

  ---jdbc-test.properties

in my case I used my blogspot-servlet-test.xml to call or to create the datasource and other configuration needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

     <!-- .... some bean configuration -->

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="file:web/WEB-INF/jdbc-test.properties"/>


    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
     </bean>

     <!-- DAO'S -->
     <bean id="blogspotDAO" class="package.BlogspotDAOImpl"/>

     <!-- SERVICES -->
     <bean id="blogspotService" class="package.BlogspotServiceImpl"/>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
     </bean>


     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

MY jdbc-test.properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/dbschemaname
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

For hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd//hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <mapping class="somePackage.entity.Author"/>
            <!-- Other Entity Class to be mapped -->

        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

and i created BaseClass for me to lessen creating of multiple @SpringApplicationContext annotation and it is also use to create common configuration needed in testing other test class,you just need to extends it.

```
@SpringApplicationContext({"file:web/WEB-INF/blogspot-servlet-test.xml"})
public class BaseServiceTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {
}
```

i used @SpringApplicationContext to load the datasource and other bean configurations  on my BaseClass from my spring configuration and this is how i implement it.

Below : see [Spring-Unitils Tutorial](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-spring.html)
 for more details

```
public class BlogspotServiceTest extends BaseServiceTest{

    @Mock //mock this object
    @InjectInto(property = "blogspotDAO") //inject the dao to the test object
    @SpringBean("blogspotDAO") //it is most likely @Autowired annotation
    private BlogspotDAO blogspotDAOMock;

    @TestedObject //annotate that this object is for test
    @SpringBean("blogspotService")
    private BlogspotService blogspotServiceMock;

    @Test
    public void testAddBlogSpot() {
        assertNotNull("BlogspotService Not null",blogspotServiceMock); //test if blogspotServiceMock is not null
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** please create unitils.properties and unitils-local.properties inside TestPackage to be able to run the program.

For @SpringBean explanation and other annotation please read :

[Unitils-EasyMock](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-spring.html)

Comment: Your post doesn't answer original question. And besides: Unitils development is almost abandoned, so IMHO do not use it.