# Spring RESTful webservice testing

Tags: spring, rest, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm trying to figure out what type of testing i should do for my project layers.
I have made Controller->Service->DAO project model.
So I need to test DAO layer with unit tests and integration tests?
And Controller with unit tests and integration tests?
I just want to know how it has to be done in a professional way that code wont be overloaded :) And maybe some one has any links to of unit testing and integration testing for my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use junit testing framework.  Go through blow links for reference.

[JUnit test cases for Spring Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091778/junit-test-cases-for-spring-service-layer)

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/spring-junit-test-example/

Comment: yeah i know about JUnit, but do I have to test all layers off app or its only enough to test controller layer?

Comment: It's up to on your requirement, what you want to test your service layer, dao layer or controller.